# My cin.fail() check is working sometimes and giving me errors other times

Tags: c++, cin

I'm trying to include a few lines of code that check cin inputs for error states, and it's working sometimes and giving me an error other times. Here's an instance where it works fine:

```
int main() {

//Introduces the game

int intro = 0;
int pronouns = 0;
int confirm_pronouns = 0;

while (intro != 1 || intro != 2) {

    do {
        std::cout << "The Eden Shard\n";
        std::cout << "Press 1 to begin. Press 2 to exit.\n\n";
        std::cin >> intro;
        if (cin.fail()) {

            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();

            std::cout << "\n\nInvalid input\n\n";
        }
    }
    while (cin.fail() == true);
```

If the user enters a character or symbol instead of an integer, it's detected, cleared, and the user is prompted again - just how I want it to work.

Here's an instance where it fails:

```
std::string assign_name() {

std::string name;
int confirm_name = 0;

do {

    std::cout << "\nWhat is your name?\n\n";
    std::cin >> name;

    do {

        std::cout << "\n\nYour name is " << name << "?\n";
        std::cout << "1. Yes\n";
        std::cout << "2. No\n\n";
        std::cin >> confirm_name;
        if (cin.fail() == true){

            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();

            std::cout << "\n\nInvalid input\n\n";
        }

        if (confirm_name != 1 && confirm_name != 2) {

            std::cout << "\nInvalid entry\n";

        }

    }

    while (confirm_name != 1 && confirm_name != 2);
}

while (confirm_name != 1);
return name;
```

}

I'm not sure what's causing the failure here when they both seem to be implemented the exact same way. The only difference is that I only get errors in my header file. The error message is C2065 - 'cin': undeclared identifier.

Comment: Perhaps the lack of `std::` in front of several uses of `cin` is the problem.

Comment: If you are not including `using namespace std` or less generic `using namespace std::cin` somewhere in your code, your `cin` must always come with a prefix `std::`